# need a better for loop to get to my second if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
         String getStringChar = event.getActionCommand();
         char c = getStringChar.charAt(0);

         int arrayLength = Game.labelArray.length;

         for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
         {

             if(Game.labelArray[i].getText().contains(""+ c))
             {
                 Game.labelArray[i].setVisible(true);

             }


            if(i == arrayLength && !(Game.labelArray[i].getText().contains(""+ c)))
            {
                score++;
                Game.setImage(score);
            }
         }
    }// end method actionPerformed
```

Comment: What does "better" mean? What is your problem?

Comment: actually what i mean is that the second if statement never gets a chance to do its work, i think the for loop is not giving a chance to fire up..

Comment: Does your code compile? Run? Produce errors? Produce unexpected results?  What **is** the problem?

Comment: it runs fine but the second if statement never gets to run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the if statement is the very last thing that needs to be done you can just execute it after the for loop with some little tweaks.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
     String getStringChar = event.getActionCommand();
     char c = getStringChar.charAt(0);

     int arrayLength = Game.labelArray.length;

     for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
     {
         if(Game.labelArray[i].getText().contains(""+ c))
         {
             Game.labelArray[i].setVisible(true);
         }      
     }

     if(!(Game.labelArray[arrayLength-1].getText().contains(""+ c)))
     {
         score++;
         Game.setImage(score);
     }
}// end method actionPerformed
```

UPDATE AFTER COMMENT

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
     String getStringChar = event.getActionCommand();
     char c = getStringChar.charAt(0);

     int arrayLength = Game.labelArray.length;

     containsCharacter = false
     for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
     {

         if(Game.labelArray[i].getText().contains(""+ c))
         {
             Game.labelArray[i].setVisible(true);
             containsCharacter = true
         }      
     }

     if(!containsCharacter)
     {
         score++;
         Game.setImage(score);
     }
}// end method actionPerformed
```

Comment: thanks but it wont get the work done for what i need. let me explain.

Comment: so this is supposed to be a hangman game, the second if must run only if all the array is checked then if the character is not in it i should increment the score, which in turn will add a body part to the hang man... if it runs at  [arrayLength-1] it will cause false increment...

Comment: So if I am understanding your code correctly, what you are actually doing now is looping to see if it contains the character. And afterwards you check the last element in the array. If this element is not the character you increment the score.

Comment: A flag variable might fix your problem

Comment: not exactly once all elements are evaluated then if none were matched, increment the score ....

Comment: a flag variable eh... not sure if i know how to do that.. :(

Comment: oh ok a bool... ill try it

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
```

`i` will **never** equal `arrayLength` in the loop body. To get the last element your second `if` should look something like (note the `- 1`)

```
if(i == arrayLength - 1 && 
    !(Game.labelArray[i].getText().contains(""+ c)))
```

Comment: exactly, _i < arrayLength_ and never execute second statement.

Comment: @jahangirhunani Yes, you get an array index out of bounds exception because `Game.labelArray[i]` is out of bounds when `i` is equal to the array length. The last element in an array is `arrayLength - 1` as I said in my answer.

Comment: labelArray[i] will throw outofrange exception.

Comment: the "if(i == arrayLength - 1 && 
    !(Game.labelArray[i].getText().contains(""+ c)))" will cause it to run too early...

Comment: @jahangirhunani No it won't. That's the last element in the array, there are no more. An array starts at 0.